# Verification if a>b>0 then cube root of a is bigger than cube root of b

Tags: proof-writing

I am trying to do this proof. Please tell me if it is correct. Please help me also with the mathematical symbols.

If a>b>0 then cube root of a is bigger than cube root of a.

**Case 1:**

Suppose for the search of contradiction that cube root of b is

bigger than cube root of a.

Then (cube root of b)*(cube root of b)>(cube root of a)*(cube root of a)

By extension, 
(cube root of b)*(cube root of b)*(cube root of b) >
(cube root of a)*(cube root of a)*(cube root of a)

Therefore, b>a, a contradiction of the starting condition.

**Case 2:**

Suppose that cube root of b is equal to cube root of a.

By the same method:

(cube root of b)*(cube root of b)*(cube root of b) =
(cube root of a)*(cube root of a)*(cube root of a)

Therefore, b=a, also a contradiction of the starting condition.

**Then, if a>b>0 then cube root of a is bigger than cube root of b. Q.E.D.**

Comment: Where do you use $a>b>0$ in your proof?

Comment: @LinAlg if negative, multiplication reverses the inequality.  But then again the second multiplication reverses that back. Just needs some care in handling the negative cases.

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you for your fast answer. As a>b>0, the cube roots are positive, Then the case that you mention does not exist. Correct?

Comment: @Macavity As a and b are positive, the cube root of them are positive too. Correct?

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your comment. I believe that I fixed the mistake. Correct?

Comment: @LinAlg I used a>b>0 in the contradictions, to assume that the cube roots are positive, and to multiply both sides without changing the inequality.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your help!

Comment: I edited one formula to show you how to format using MathJax (essentially TeX/LateX). Either edit the answer to see or right click on the formula and select 'Show Math As'->'TeX Commands'.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you! I will try!

Comment: @copper.hat I am sorry. I tried to follow what you did, but I was not successful.  Even, it seems that I erased what you did, that was very nice.

Comment: NP. There are a lot of little details. If you look at the edit history (click on edited $n$ mins ago) you will see what I did.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you so much!

Comment: You still need to show that the cube root is positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is correct, with the addition of what you state as obvious: if $\sqrt[3]{b}>\sqrt[3]{a}$, then
$$
\sqrt[3]{b}\sqrt[3]{b}>\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{b}>\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{a}
$$
and similarly for the next step.

However, the proof can be simplified: you don't need to do separate cases for $>$ and $=$, for instance.

On the other hand, you can recall $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$, so
$$
0<a-b=(\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b})
\underbrace{((\sqrt[3]{a})^2+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{b}+(\sqrt[3]{b})^2)}_{>0}
$$
and therefore $\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}>0$.